# Data not getting populated into influxdb but returns status code 204

Tags: java, database, time-series, influxdb

We are using influxdb in our application and found some rows are getting duplicated for same tags and timestamp. So I deleted all the records for that tag and tried inserting data for that tag again. But I can see data are not getting populated in influx even though I am getting 204 as response.

I tried inserting data to another db by changing database name and I am able see the data getting populated into db.

Comment: We are using influx version 1.4.2 and influxdb-java driver version 2.7 in our application. Also tried inserting data for same tags using CLI and I can see the data getting populated into influx.

Comment: Elaborate on how exactly you're trying to do that, please. Show the InfluxQL/CLI/whatever sentences you use.